# Ext is not definied in ext.net mvc

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, ext.net

Currently, I am start to use ext.net mvc. So, everything is new for me. Please help me for it. It is  showing ext is not defined. I think that it is missing some js file.I created Indext.cshtml and code as below:
Thank you in advance.

```
  @{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
  }

<script>
Ext.onReady(function () {
    alert('start');
var myparams1 = new Object();
myparams1.id = 1;
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'Services/AService.svc/GetMyData'      
    method: 'GET',
    success: function (response, options) {
        // response callback
        alert('Success');

    },
    failure: function (response, options) {
        Ext.MessageBox.alert('Failed', 'Unable to get');
    }

});
});        
</script>
```

Comment: The following thread in the Ext.NET forums might help solve the problem: http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?18136-Ext-is-not-defined

Answer (score 0):

I just found the link.We can link ext-base and ext-all in cshtml.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://extjs-public.googlecode.com/svn/tags/ext-2.2/release/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://extjs-public.googlecode.com/svn/tags/ext-2.2/release/ext-all.js"></script>
```